# What will happen if a hypernova blast occurs very near to a supermassive black hole?

Tags: black-holes, astrophysics, supernova

I ve studied that blackholes swallow everything that comes near to them and a supernova blast is so powerful that if it occurs at one end of our solar system it will destroy whole of it . What will happen if both meets?

Comment: I have reverted the question. Harsh jain, if you are not able to ask a new question, replacing an existing question is *not* an acceptable way to circumvent that restriction.

Comment: "blackholes swallow everything that comes near to them" is a common misconception.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably more common than you might expect. Stars frequently form binary systems and in a binary system of two very massive stars it is quite possible that first one star may form a black hole then the other star go supernova (the second star may well subsequently form a black hole as well). This almost certainly happened in the black hole binary systems detected by the LIGO experiment.

But you have to remember that stellar mass black holes are surprisingly small. A black hole with the mass of the Sun will have a radius on only about 3km. In the case of the binary star system the supernova will fling off a huge amount of matter but only a tiny fraction of that matter will hit its companion black hole. Most of the debris from the supernova will just go flying off into space.

The matter that hits the black hole will be absorbed by it, probably causing high intensity X-ray emission, but this isn't going to make a huge difference to the overall energy released by the supernova. The matter hitting the black hole will exert a force on it, though whether this is enough to push the two stars out of their mutual orbit I don't know.

The bottom line is that the fact a black hole is present during a supernova doesn't make a lot of difference to what is already an awe inspiring (literally!) event.

Comment: *black hole with the mass of the Sun* the question asked about supermassive bh.

Comment: Its a supermassive blackhole with mass of billions of sun and not just 1